# Cant start resque worker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, resque

I've installed [resque](https://github.com/resque/resque) gem, `gem install resque`.

And I tried to start the workers :

```
bundle exec rake environment resque:work
```

Resulting in :

```
rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'resque:work' (see --tasks)

(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

When I do `rake -T` no resque tasks appear, what am I going wrong here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. You should put the `resque` gem into the `Gemfile` instead of installing it directly.
2. [Installation documentation (as of the time of writing)](https://github.com/resque/resque/blob/4b04fb8cfafe1e22976954aea5df6f1b701ee161/README.markdown#in-a-rails-3-app-as-a-gem) says that...

> To start a worker, add this to a file in lib/tasks (ex: lib/tasks/resque.rake):
>
> ```
> require 'resque/tasks'
> ```

Comment: Tried it both ways, same result